# Flipper Network Plugin doesn't show network requests

Tags: android, plugins, native, fbflipper

According to the [documents](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/android-native) here, I followed the necessary steps. Yet, even though I can see the requested data when I debug my app, I see no network traffic on Flipper. Here is my code:

#### Dependencies:

```
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.54.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.54.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0'
```

#### Application Setup:

```
class MoveeApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initFlipper()
    }

    private fun initFlipper() {
        SoLoader.init(this, false)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG && FlipperUtils.shouldEnableFlipper(this)) {
            val flipperClient = AndroidFlipperClient.getInstance(this)
            val networkFlipperPlugin = NetworkFlipperPlugin()
            flipperClient.addPlugin(
                InspectorFlipperPlugin(
                    this@MoveeApp,
                    DescriptorMapping.withDefaults()
                )
            )
            flipperClient.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin)
            flipperClient.start()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Network Module where I provide OkHttpClient:

The document says [here](https://fbflipper.com/docs/setup/network-plugin#okhttp-integration) *"As interceptors can modify the request and response, add the Flipper interceptor after all others to get an accurate view of the network traffic."*. That's why I added network interceptor after I added the request interceptor, as can be seen below.

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(requestInterceptor: RequestInterceptor): OkHttpClient =
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(NetworkFlipperPlugin()))
            .build()
}
```

The desktop app's version is "0.54.0" as well and Network plugin is enabled.

Is there something I fail to notice?

Answer (score 3):

In function `provideOkHttpClient` the code is creating a new instance of `NetworkFlipperPlugin` that is not registered with the flipper client.

In `MoveeApp` the code is also creating a `NetworkFlipperPlugin` that is coupled to the flipper client, but that plugin is not registered as an interceptor.

Expose the flipper network plugin in MoveeApp and retrieve it, something like:

```
.addNetworkInterceptor(FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(MoveeApp.flipperNetworkPlugin))
```

Comment: this is working for me. Before I was instantiating like this ``MoveeApp().flipperNetworkPlugin`` and it is still not working. I have to create a companion object and create a variable ``lateinit var instance`` and set it at ``onCreate`` on MoveeApp. Something like this: ``instance = this``. After that I can instantiate the plugin like this ``MoveeApp.instance.flipperNetworkPlugin``